# Nested Attribute Not Creating Rails 4 - Multi Tennant App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am building an app (Rails 4) and implementing a subscription plan, The workflow is as such:

An account is created, when the account is created the owner is created with it and a plan is also supposed to be created with it.

this is the server output when the account is created:

```
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "confirmation_token", "confirmation_sent_at", "f_name", "l_name", "date_of_birth", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "swilson@patrolvault.net"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$ZFMl7BhZc3a.DnoyfiEuYO7bXqLeZ9smhhg4J.JaK00APGFdpVsgG"], ["confirmation_token", "LmdZXcuL7GJYP6nqWKvm"], ["confirmation_sent_at", 2016-10-19 02:19:21 UTC], ["f_name", "Some"], ["l_name", "Owner"], ["date_of_birth", Mon, 01 Jan 1900], ["created_at", 2016-10-19 02:19:21 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-10-19 02:19:21 UTC]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "public"."accounts" ("subdomain", "owner_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "image_data") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["subdomain", "testdomain1"], ["owner_id", 1], ["created_at", 2016-10-19 02:19:21 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-10-19 02:19:21 UTC], ["image_data", "{\"id\":\"536fe1bc4a8a95d64d81dd2e4f4e10af.png\",\"storage\":\"cache\",\"metadata\":{\"filename\":\"Pvaulticon.png\",\"size\":9419,\"mime_type\":\"image/png\"}}"]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "plans" ("account_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["account_id", 1], ["created_at", 2016-10-19 02:19:21 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-10-19 02:19:21 UTC]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "public"."accounts" SET "updated_at" = $1, "image_data" = $2 WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" = $3  [["updated_at", 2016-10-19 02:19:21 UTC], ["image_data", "{\"id\":\"299bf4eba233a14d65e94ea9d85893f6.png\",\"storage\":\"store\",\"metadata\":{\"filename\":\"Pvaulticon.png\",\"size\":9419,\"mime_type\":\"image/png\"}}"], ["id", 1]]
   (6.3ms)  COMMIT
```

However when I try to query the plan in Rails Console it returns this:

```
2.3.1 :004 > Plan.all
  Plan Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "plans".* FROM "plans"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

2.3.1 :007 > a.plan.plan_type
  Plan Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans" WHERE "plans"."account_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["account_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `plan_type' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):7
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/developer/Desktop/PatrolVault-Saas/PV_SAAS/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/developer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

**Here is my Account Model:**

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  include ImageUploader[:image]
  # Constants
  RESTRICTED_SUBDOMAINS = %w(www patrolvault admin test type taurenapplabs taurenmaterialservices)

  # Before Actions
  before_validation :downcase_subdomain

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
  has_many :users

  # Validations
  validates :owner, presence: true

  validates :subdomain, presence: true,
                        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                        format: { with: /\A[\w\-]+\Z/i, message: 'Contains invalid characters.' },
                        exclusion: { in: RESTRICTED_SUBDOMAINS, message: 'Restricted domain name'}

  has_one :plan
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :plan

  private

  def downcase_subdomain
    self.subdomain = self.subdomain.downcase
  end

end
```

**This is my Plan Model:**

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  # Enum & Constants
  enum plan_type: [:responder, :first_responder, :patrol_pro, :guardian]

  USER_LIMITS = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(
    responder:        6,
    first_responder:  12,
    patrol_pro:       30,
    guardian:         60
  )

  # Before Actions

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :account, optional: true

end
```

**And here is the Account Controller:**

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @account = Account.new
    @account.build_owner
    @account.build_plan
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.valid?
        Apartment::Tenant.create(@account.subdomain)
        Apartment::Tenant.switch!(@account.subdomain)
        @account.save
        format.html {redirect_to new_user_session_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain)}
      else
        format.html {render :new}
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:subdomain, :image, plan_attributes: [:plan_type, :id], owner_attributes: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :f_name, :l_name, :date_of_birth])
  end

  def set_account
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

**and the Plan Controller:**

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController

  private

  def plan_params
    params.require(:plan).permit(:account_id, :plan_type)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your plan being created outside the account tenant? I see you switch tenants after creating the account so possibly it creates the record, but then it’s not visible because it’s in the global tenant

You might need Plan to be a global model like Account that lives outside tenants.